# Why am I getting "Cannot read property of html undefined"?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am building a simple counter to practice closures in JS, and I can't seem to get past this error. In my mind setting the variable elem to the id of canv should work, but something is obviously not connecting. What am I doing wrong here?

**My HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="canv">

  </div>
</body>
```

**My JS:**

```
function setup(delay) {
  var el = document.getElementById('canv');

  counterFn(el, delay);
}

function counterFn(el, delay) {
  var counter = 0;

  setInterval(getTime, delay);

  function getTime(el) {
    el.innerHTML(counter);
    counter++;
  }
}

setup(500);
```

This all feels very elementary but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here's a JS fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/8sjaqdrh/2/

Comment: When is your JavaScript ran? It's probably trying to access your canvas before it exist in the DOM and hence `document.getElementById('canv')` would give `undefined`. Although along with this you are not giving the local `el` a value when you call `getTime` anyways, so it would be undefined in that case too. You need to fix both of those issues to get this to work.

Comment: @PatrickBarr oops I didn't realize that. But I started out with innerHTML and it is the same exact error. (ill update my post though)

Comment: `getTime` expects an argument, but it is never passed. `el` in the argument list makes it local variable to `getTime`, `e` in the outer scope is shadowed. Aand `innerHTML` is not a function.

Comment: probably you are calling `setup` too early, before DOM is ready. try to call it in window.onload= function(){ setup(500); }

Comment: Also I think innerHTML is usually set with el.innerHTML = counter;

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I thought that but wouldn't it find it on the 2nd pass from the setInterval? I also added the `window.onload = setup(500);` just now and that didn't help either.

Comment: Just remove `el` from the argument list of `getTime`, and use `innerHTML` as a string.

Comment: @crescentfresh You define it only once before either of the intervals, as I mentioned there are several other issues here. Including that `.innerHTML(counter);` should be `.innerHTML = counter;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that caused the error is because `el` is not defined within the scope of `getTime`.

In getTime's parent scope `counterFn`, `el` is defined because you gave it a value when calling it in `counterFn(el, delay)` inside `setup` function, which is `el = document.getElementById('canv')`.

However in the scope of `getTime`, you did not provide `el` with a value. So `el` becomes `undefined`.

Another problem with the code is the incorrect usage of `innerHTML`.

Just removing the parameter from `function getTime(el){...` to `function getTime(){...` will do.

As for `innerHTML`, it is not a function. So it can't be called like `innerHTML(counter)`.

The correct way is to directly assign a value to it like `innerHTML = counter`.

```js
function setup(delay) {
  var el = document.getElementById('canv');

  counterFn(el, delay);
}

function counterFn(el, delay) {
  var counter = 0;

  setInterval(getTime, delay);

  // Corrected code:
  function getTime() {
    el.innerHTML = counter;
    counter++;
  }
  
  /* Your code
  function getTime(el){
    el.innerHTML(counter);
    counter++;
  }
  */
}

setup(500);
```

```html
<div id="canv"></div>
```

Comment: I think the biggest issue was passing `el` as a parameter to `getTime` without calling the function in that way. I screwed up with my jsfiddle edits so I accidentally posted it here as `innerHTML(counter)`. Thanks for your help! I need to keep practicing debugging.

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue here is that your trying to get the canvas before it exist in the DOM, you will want to wrap your code in a `window.onload` event to prevent that from happening.

Next for the code bellow here:

```
setInterval(getTime, delay);
```

You define `getTime` as expecting a parameter but did not pass one, instead you will want do to:

```
setInterval(function(){ getTime(el); }, wait);
```

Finally `el.innerHTML(counter);` should be `el.innerHTML = counter;`.

[**Working Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/8sjaqdrh/3/)